# Font identification request -- Clean, rounded edges, sans-serif, really attractive

Tags: fonts, typography, font-identification

This is a very common font but I can't remember it. I saw it suddenly on my keyboard just now. The image actually doesn't appear clear until you zoom in on it.

(I tried automatic font-ID sites but as the picture is of a keyboard, they failed).

[image: Image of a Dell keyboard]

Comment: What font-id services did you try? If you get a better close-up picture of one specific key, you should be able to put it trough one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try Montserrate. I love this font and currently creating a website using the same font. I'm sure this is the most closest font with this one..

but I searched through http://www.identifont.com/ for you.. and found.

Following list of matching fonts..

http://www.identifont.com/list?17+22-.-2G-2E-2BT-4A-6X5-4PX-JPK-8Z-Z-1LB-1KU-6XA-2L-1KK-2U-1A-53L-42-1R0-1U-9Z+1.14+3AQO+1+3AQN+1+3AQF+1+3AQE+1+3AQK+1+3AQD+1+3AQM+1+3AQI+1+3AQG+1+3AQH+1+3AQJ+1+6WX+2+2Y1E+3+46K+6

in the above link.. check left list. one by one and on the right.. closet matching fonts.

Comment: also look at http://www.findafont.com/

Comment: None of them are exact matches (the "1" is the biggest difference) but they both will do, thanks a lot!

Comment: some times fonts are prepared only for company use. may be altered some already commercially available fonts. similarly some fonts are good in CAPS and others are in lower case, some a good in Numbers and others are in glyphs .. it's a kind of mix workout..